# Call combined reselect selector from redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, reselect

I am trying to call a combined selector from `redux-saga`. The idea is that I have two drop downs. Choices in first drop down will filter the appropriate values in second drop down, i.e. my combined selector will filter out some non relevant values, so they will not be shown in second drop down:

1) I have two selectors, `firstSelector` and `secondSelector`

```
// firstSelector returns {"Cat":["black","white"],"Dog":["grey"]}
const firstSelector= () =>
  createSelector(selectPage, substate => substate.firstDropDown);

// secondSelector returns ["black","grey"]
const secondSelector= () =>
  createSelector(selectPage, substate => substate.secondDropDown);
```

2) I combine those in combined selector (which should return `["black", "grey"]`, i.e. "white" is filtered out)

```
const filterBySelection = (firstSelector, secondSelector) =>
  createSelector(
    [
      firstSelector, 
      secondSelector, 
    ],
    (first, second) => {
      const filteredValues = Object.keys(first).reduce(
        (r, k) => r.concat(first[k]),
        [],
      );
      return second.filter(val => filteredValues.indexOf(val) >= 0);
    },
  );
```

3) But how can I call `filterBySelection` in `redux-saga`?
I tried:

```
const filteredValues = yield select(
  filterBySelection,
  firstSelector,
  secondSelector,
);
```

And

```
const filteredValues = yield select(
  filterBySelection(firstSelector, secondSelector)()
);
```

And

```
const filteredValues = yield select(
  filterBySelection(firstSelector, secondSelector)
);
```

But those ways do not work.

Though, I can call `firstSelector` or `secondSelector`, i.e. works:

```
const firstData= yield select(firstSelector());
```

Someone can say that I can simply do the below in redux-saga:

```
const first = yield select(firstSelector());
const second = yield select(secondSelector());
const filtered = Object.keys(first).reduce(
  (r, k) => r.concat(first[k]),
  [],
);
const secondFiltered = second.filter(
  val => first.indexOf(val) >= 0,
);
```

But that will `not memoize` and the idea is to `memoize`.

So is it possible to use a memoized selector in redux-saga?

Best Regards

Comment: I think you can drop array in createSelector, just pass the subSelectors as arguments

Comment: ```const filterBySelection = (firstSelector, secondSelector) =>
  createSelector(
      firstSelector, 
      secondSelector, 
    (first, second) => {
      const filteredValues = Object.keys(first).reduce(
        (r, k) => r.concat(first[k]),
        [],
      );
      return second.filter(val => filteredValues.indexOf(val) >= 0);
    },
  );```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to miss call the function to return the selector. So, either:

a)

```
const filterBySelection = (firstSelector, secondSelector) =>
  createSelector(
    [
       firstSelector(), // <- parentheses 
       secondSelector(), // <- parentheses 
     ], ... )
```

then: `const filteredValues = yield select(
  filterBySelection(firstSelector, secondSelector)
);`

b) pass selectors correctly

```
const filteredValues = yield select(
  filterBySelection(firstSelector(), secondSelector())
);
```

c) define `firstSelector` and `secondSelector` without function (perhaps the most true way):

```
const firstSelector = 
  createSelector(selectPage, substate => substate.firstDropDown);

const secondSelector = 
  createSelector(selectPage, substate => substate.secondDropDown);
```

then

```
const filteredValues = yield select(
  filterBySelection(firstSelector, secondSelector)
);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Correct... I missed to call selectors in combined selector:P thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this

````
  createSelector(
    firstSelector, 
    secondSelector, 
    (first, second) => {
      const filteredValues = Object.keys(first).reduce(
        (r, k) => r.concat(first[k]),
        [],
      );
      return second.filter(val => filteredValues.indexOf(val) >= 0);
    },
  );```
````

Comment: That is my selector exactly. It is not the question / problem.

Comment: I'm saying, that you should drop the array

Comment: and with dropping the array you don't need to use parentheses ()

Comment: Thank you! I found this very helpful. I combined a separate selector into the main one and everything worked. Before the separate selector was causing issues (search term filtering as well as separate radio filters).